# Https and SSL issue with port 80

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, digital-ocean

Recently I just start using https:// for my server and the strange thing is that I can open if I explicitly type "https://www.example.com:80" but won't be able to connect if i type "https://www.example.com".

I am using NodeJS with Express 4 framework hosted on Digital Ocean.

What can I do to let people access my website normally? And also is it normal that they have to click "accept" first time they visit? Why for other https website I dont have to do that?

I am using RapidSSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is light on details, but here are the two likely guesses:

1. If you want your SSL server to work by default when users type `https://xxxx`, then your server needs to be running on port 443, not port 80.  That's the default port number reserved for https connections and is the port number that the browser will try if the user just enters a `https://xxxx` URL.
2. If the browser is prompting you for permission to connect to your site, then that is likely because the SSL certificate you are using is not signed by one of the certificate authorities that the browsers trust (perhaps it is a self signed certificate).  You can solve that issue by getting a certificate from the right trusted source and using that certificate in your server.  It's also a possibility that something else is wrong with your SSL configuration, but we'd need to see more detail about the situation to know.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think they key is to use port 443 and not port 80. I made that big mistake! Now everything is working as intended and no prompt! All I did was 
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000